# Why is easygraphics only giving me a blank screen in RENDER_MODE_AUTO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

so i recently started playing around with the `easygraphics` library, following some coding challenges. When I started my current project, I was using `RENDER_MODE_MANUAL`, according to some sample `easygraphics` code. The whole time I had trouble with clearing the screen at the right time, using `delay_fps()` properly and so on, so towards the end I decided to try out `RENDER_MODE_AUTO`. Problem is, the program refuses drawing anything for me, neither background or lines. I really don't see anything wrong with my approach and it's relatively difficult to find good information regarding `easygraphics` online.

My main.py code:

```
from easygraphics import *
import math
from branch import Branch
import time

width = 1280
height = 720
length = 150
angle = math.pi / 2
tree = []
branches = []



def mainloop():
    global angle
    n = 0

    a = [width / 2, height]
    b = [width / 2, height - length]
    root = Branch(a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1])
    tree.append(root)

    while is_run():
        if n < 5:
            time.sleep(2)
            brancher()
        elif n == 5:
            time.sleep(100)
        n += 1
        print(n)

        for branch in tree:
            branch.draw()


def brancher():
    new_branches = []  
    for branch in tree[:]:
        new_branches.append(branch.branchR())
        new_branches.append(branch.branchL())
    tree.extend(new_branches)


def main():
    init_graph(width, height)
    set_background_color("#333333")
    set_color("#ffffff")
    set_line_width(2)
    set_render_mode(RenderMode.RENDER_AUTO)
    mainloop()
    close_graph()


easy_run(main)
```

My branch.py:

```
from easygraphics import *
import numpy as np
import math

sizeMult = 0.67


def rotateVector(vector, degrees):
    newVector = np.empty(2)
    newVector[0] = math.cos(degrees) * vector[0] - math.sin(degrees) * vector[1]
    newVector[1] = math.sin(degrees) * vector[0] + math.cos(degrees) * vector[1]
    return newVector


class Branch:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2

    def draw(self):
        line(self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2)

    def branchR(self):
        vec = np.array([self.x2, self.y2]) - np.array([self.x1, self.y1])
        vec = rotateVector(vec, math.degrees(math.pi / 4))
        vec[0] = vec[0] * sizeMult
        vec[1] = vec[1] * sizeMult
        newEnd = np.array([self.x2, self.y2]) + vec
        right = Branch(self.x2, self.y2, newEnd[0], newEnd[1])
        return right

    def branchL(self):
        vec = np.array([self.x2, self.y2]) - np.array([self.x1, self.y1])
        vec = rotateVector(vec, -math.degrees(math.pi / 4))
        vec[0] = vec[0] * sizeMult
        vec[1] = vec[1] * sizeMult
        newEnd = np.array([self.x2, self.y2]) + vec
        left = Branch(self.x2, self.y2, newEnd[0], newEnd[1])
        return left
```

I apologize for the lack of comments.

Any suggestions? I'd be open to try `RENDER_MODE_MANUAL` again, but I'd need some pointers as to how.

Many thanks

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and I'm using PyCharm. I have the package installed through PyCharm's integrated package installer.

Comment: Are you using this from within an IDE, or directly from a command line?  And which operating system is this?

Comment: See edit above, my apologies

Comment: Running Python inside an IDE causes very strange interactions with GUI apps.  As an experiment, you might try running your script from a command line, but my GUESS is that the real answer is going to be `RenderMode.MANUAL`.  That is a double-buffered approach that is usually better anyway.

Comment: Yeah running it via the terminal results in a blank white screen with n updating properly still. 
I don't wanna ask too much of you, but could you give me some pointers for how to handle the delay_fps() and clear_device() situation? For the RENDER_MODE_MANUAL implementation i mean

Comment: First, throw out the `time.sleep` calls.  They are NEVER appropriate in a GUI app, because all they do is block the main thread.  What you should be using is `delay_fps(30)` to have the display update 30 times per second.